# Inline worker is not supported

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, testing

I am new to Vue.js and originally to testing.

so I am trying to write test for my component but this error occurs and I don't know were this error raises from and how to resolve it.
[console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3OtB.png)

and this is the test code that I'm trying to execute.
[test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sSAM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including `@vitest/web-worker` ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34772592)